# use same paypal ipn for multiple stores

Tags: paypal-ipn

I am building a WordPress website using:

- Sugar Events Calendar & Sugar Events Calendar & Gravity Forms Integration plugin
- WooCommerce store selling a couple of products

I have enabled the PayPal IPN and specified the URL for your listener in the Notification URL field. I used the Gravity Forms URL from the plugin.

So, I am ( want to ) using PayPal IPN (Basic PayPal service) with Multiple Stores With 1 Paypal Account. I am not sure how this will work when there is a purchase from the WooCommerce store. I think they will get the Gravity Forms notification? Do I need a script to dynamically call the notification form each store?

Thanks,
Doak

Comment: I use this service: https://ipnforwarder.com/ so then I can change the notify url when ever i want (and also can send the ipn to multiple urls)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass over the IPN URL that you want to use with each transaction.  If you are using Website Payments Standard, you can use the variable `notify_url`.  Then just set your value to the IPN URL that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, if I understand I need to add a script ( ipn.php ) as the 'Notification URL' in the PayPal IPN settings page redirecting to either store?

Comment: Correct, you can pass over the IPN URL in your code.  This way you can have several/stores using different IPN URL's.